# Repeat a jQuery AJAX POST function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a clickable div loading the next 5 comments from my database, sort of how Twitter loads new tweets into your timeline. I have a few other POST functions in my code and they can be fired off multiple times, but this one won't.

Here's the code - the comments are returned from a URL (the site is codeigniter), inserted into a hidden div, then the div is slid down.

```
$(".content .load-more-comments").live("click", load_messages);
function load_messages() {
    var offset = 10;
    var count = 5;
    $.post((site_url+'project/load_more_messages/'+project_id), { count:count, offset:offset }, function(data) {
        if(data) {
            var more_messages = data;
            $("ul.messages").append('<div class="slidedown" style="display:none;">'+data+'</div>');
            $("ul.messages div.slidedown").slideDown(1000);
            var offset = offset+5;
        } else {
            $("ul.messages").append('<p class="error">Additional messages could not be loaded.</p>');
        };
    });
    return false;   
};
```

Like I said, it works fine the first time, but after that, no dice. My guess is that something in the function is still running, but I tried to end anything running and that didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean to reset your offset each time you call load_messages?

Comment: Do you mean to add a new "slidedown" class div for every ajax post?

Comment: Where do site_url and project_id come from? You seem to want offset to be increased by 5. But the `offset+5`you have there is a local variable

Answer (score 2):

These are the offending lines:

```
var offset = 10;
var count = 5;
```

Everytime a click occurs your offset & count be reset to 10 & 5 respectively. Methinks you need to make these variable declarations global, outside the `load_messages()` function.

Comment: I actually noticed that earlier and changed it, but that didn't affect anything. I don't think the function is running a second time.